# Purpose of the "class_stub" File in PHP Cache for PrestaShop Development

Tags: php, caching, prestashop

As a developer working with PrestaShop, I've come across a file named "class_stub" in the cache directory of my application. This file contains class declarations that follow this pattern:

```
class Access extends AccessCore {};
class Address extends AddressCore {};
class AddressChecksum extends AddressChecksumCore {};
// ... and so on for other classes
```

I'm delving into the technical aspects and wondering about the role of this "class_stub" file specifically in the context of PrestaShop development. Could you provide insights into why these classes are structured like this within the cache? Do these classes serve a particular purpose in the PrestaShop application's architecture? I'm curious why these declarations are cached in this manner instead of being included directly from their original source files.

Your expertise in PrestaShop's caching mechanism and its impact on development would be invaluable in helping me understand this better. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know anything about Prestashop, but I can tell you that this 'class_stub' seems to simplify the names of core classes. So `AccessCore` can now also be used as `Access`, and so on. This doesn't look very useful to me. I think the 'stub' past means that normally these classes get a more useful extension, and that this is here in case they don't? I agree that it looks weird.